# Casting JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jmenuitem

Inside my `actionPerformed` method I have the two following lines of code,

```
JButton pressed =(JButton)e.getSource();
JMenuItem pressedSave = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();
```

Why is this not allowed? I get the following compiler error

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JButton cannot be cast to javax.swing.JMenuItem

I need to be able to get the text for both a `JButton` and a `JMenuItem`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is very clear. You are trying to assign a `Jbutton` to a `JMenuItem`.

You are getting the error on **line 2**, which means that **line 1** is flawless, which also implies that `e.getSource()` is a `JButton`, not a `JMenuItem`.

What you can do is use the `instanceof` operator to determine which component triggered the event:

```
Object comp = e.getSource();

if(comp instanceof JButton) {
    // A JButton triggered the event
    JButton pressed =(JButton) comp;

    // Do something with your 'pressed' button
}
else if(comp instanceof JMenuItem) {
    // A JMenuItem triggered the event
    JMenuItem pressedSave = (JMenuItem) comp;

    // Do something with your 'pressedSave' menu item
}
```

Comment: I do not understand though, how am i trying to assign a jbutton to jmenuitem? its a brand new object. How would I fix this?

Comment: @ugCode in what way is it a brand new object, it is the source of the event.

Answer (score 1):

**You are not getting a compiler error.**

It is *"allowed"*, it just does not work.

If it was not allowed, then the compiler would complain.

But what you have got here is a RuntimeException because you *have* a `JButton` which simply cannot be cast to a `JMenuItem`. They are unrelated types - how should a conversion / cast between those two look like?

What you *can* do is cast both types `JButton` and `JMenuItem` to their common supertype [`AbstractButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html).

Answer (score 1):

JMenuItem is not a subclass of JButton, however you can cast both to AbstractButton. That may work depending on what you want to do